# Dynamically generated content reloads unchanged

Tags: jquery

I’m just getting to grips with Jquery.

Issue: I want a user to be able to update information from a dynamically generated list by opening the detail in a fancybox for editing (hence I’m using .live with click).  All works except if a user opens a fancybox and then updates information (it posts fine and updates the DB using the below) and then closes and reopens the fancybox window the dynamically generated content reloads unchanged. I guessing that the browser is caching the page. How, can I force the updated information be loaded on reopening the facnybox window?

Also, if you can advise if the below code could be improved.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#UpdateLink").live('click', function() { 
   $('#txtHint1').fadeIn('fast').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"  />');
    var formData = $('#UpdateLinkForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Link-Updater.asp",
        data: formData,
        success: function(d) {                  
        $('#txtHint1').empty().html(d).delay(800).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

});

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try disabling cache for AJAX calls:

```
// Disable caching of AJAX responses
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});
```

Comment: Great, that did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the above cache option fails a second method is to append a random string parameter to the url. I suggest using the current timestamp so it reads like this:

```
Link-Updater.asp?rand=123456789
```

The string itself is relatively easy to build in javascript.